# Bootstrap popover stay on content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this working bootstrap popover, which works fine with time attribute.
But I want it to have the functionality of when someone has their mouse on the content it should not close and should close when mouse leaves the content.

Below is the code related to it. https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/eLLaacju/5/

HTML

```
<div>
Title
</div>
<div class="container">
<i id="popover-a" class="circle-macro" tabindex="0" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">i</i>

<div id="popover-content-a" class="hidden">
 <div>
  <h6><b>Heading</b></h6>
   <p>Content <a href="#">Click Me</a></p>
 </div>
</div>
<br>

<i id="popover-b" class="circle-macro" tabindex="1" data-container="body" data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right">i</i>

<div id="popover-content-b" class="hidden">
 <div>
  <h6><b>Heading</b></h6>
   <p>Content <a href="#">Click Me</a></p>
 </div>
</div>

</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function () {
  $("#popover-a").popover({
    html: true, trigger: 'hover', delay: {show:50, hide: 1000},
    content: function(){
      return $('#popover-content-a').html();     
    }
  });
  $("#popover-b").popover({
    html: true, trigger: 'hover', delay: {show:50, hide: 1000},
    content: function(){
      return $('#popover-content-b').html();     
    }
  });
});
```

CSS:

```
.circle-macro {
    border-radius: 50%;
    background-color: rgb(68, 104, 125);
    color: white;
    padding: 0 8px;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
    font-style: italic;
    z-index: 10;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.hidden{
  display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/bob_js/eLLaacju/6/

jQuery

```
$(function () {
  $("#popover-a").popover({
    html: true, trigger: 'manual', animation:false,
    content: function(){
      return $('#popover-content-a').html();     
    }
  }).on("mouseenter", function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
});
  $("#popover-b").popover({
    html: true, trigger: 'manual', animation:false,
    content: function(){
      return $('#popover-content-b').html();     
    }
  }).on("mouseenter", function () {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");
        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function () {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    }).on("mouseleave", function () {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function () {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 300);
});
});
```

I have updated it and this works fine, found it in stackoverflow as well.
http://plnkr.co/edit/x2VMhh?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that when the user moves the mouse on the popover, it should not close, then here is a code I use for this. Credits go to the author of [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WojtekKruszewski/Zf3m7/22) for the original idea and code.

```
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave = (function(fn) {
  return function(obj) {
    var self = obj instanceof this.constructor ?
      obj : $(obj.currentTarget).data("bs." + this.type);
    if (!self) {
      self = new this.constructor(obj.currentTarget, this.getDelegateOptions());
      $(obj.currentTarget).data("bs." + this.type, self);
    }

    var container, timeout;

    fn(obj);

    if (self.$tip && self.$tip.length) {
      container = self.$tip;
      timeout = self.timeout;
      container.off("mouseenter.popover").one("mouseenter.popover", () => {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        container.off("mouseleave.popover").one("mouseleave.popover", () => {
          $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave.call(self, self);
        });
      });
    }
  };
})($.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.leave);
```

What it does is basically captures mouse enters on the popover, and denies closing the popover.

Comment: Yes I guess. Thank you for pointing it out, I'll include it for credits.